# Check if open browser windows contains a specific string

Tags: javascript, browser

Suppose i have a website that opens multiple windows at once. The number
of open windows is unknown and the text in each window is unknown. 
how shall i test or make sure that at least the following strings (apple, banana,
carrot, date) are contained in the set of windows.

Bearing in mind that There can only be one string per page for example:

- Window 1 - Carrot
- Window 2 - Apple
- Window 5 - Date
- Window 10 -  Banana

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your five browser has five address. You can get page content with `URLConnection`, than search specific word on that content. Loop following code with the addresses of browsers.

```
    String[] strings = {"apple", "banana", "carrot", "date"};
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        output.append(inputLine);
    }
    for (String token : strings) {
       if(output.indexOf(token) != -1){
           System.out.println(token +" is found at "+ output.indexOf(token));
       }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer would be great if only i knew how many pages will it open (you assumed its five and also assumed that i know their addresses). If knew anything it would be on the first page address which if i visited it will open and unknown number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thTny/1) demonstrating how you might be able to do this.  I am relying on jQuery and browser localStorage so the solution will not work on ancient browsers.  Stick the code inside your

```
$(document).ready
```

and test the

```
localStorage.allHaves
```

bitfield to see who else is around from each of the windows (the code can be shared).  Remember to do a

```
parseInt
```

on the localStorage.allHaves value after you get it!

Comment: I have just corrected a minor copy & paste bug I had in the fiddle so if you use it make sure you use the right version!

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution, using jquery, showing you all the main functionality that you need is,

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var searchForWords = [['Carrot',false],['Apple',false],['Date',false],['Banana',false]]


    var windows=[];
    windows.push(openWindow(1));
    windows.push(openWindow(2));
    windows.push(openWindow(3));
    windows.push(openWindow(4));

    windows.forEach(function(w){
        searchForWords.forEach(function(word){
            if($(w.document).find('body').html().indexOf(word[0])!=-1){
                console.log('found word'+word[0]);
                word[1]=true;
            }
        });
    });

    var allFound = true;
    searchForWords.forEach(function(word){
        if(!word[1]){
            allFound=false;
            return;
        }
    });

    if(allFound){
        alert('all words found');
    }else{
        alert('did not find all words!');
    }


});

function openWindow(wId) {
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.write('<html><head><title>test</title>');
    w.document.write($("#test" + wId).html());
    w.document.write('</body></html>');
    w.document.close();
    return w;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="check content"></input><!-- this button is used in 2nd version, http://jsfiddle.net/xtxK9/1/ -->


<div id="test1" class="test-content">this is content for the test window1 Carrot</div>
<div id="test2" class="test-content">this is content for the test window2 Apple</div>
<div id="test3" class="test-content">this is content for the test window3 Date</div>
<div id="test4" class="test-content">this is content for the test window4 Banana</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test-content {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtxK9/

Another version invoking a "checkContent" function when clicking the button can be found here,

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var searchForWords = [['Carrot',false],['Apple',false],['Date',false],['Banana',false]]


    var windows=[];
    windows.push(openWindow(1));
    windows.push(openWindow(2));
    windows.push(openWindow(3));
    windows.push(openWindow(4));

    $('#check-button').click(function(){checkContent(searchForWords,windows);});
});

function checkContent(searchForWords,openWindows){
    openWindows.forEach(function(w){
        searchForWords.forEach(function(word){
            if($(w.document).find('body').html().indexOf(word[0])!=-1){
                console.log('found word'+word[0]);
                word[1]=true;
            }
        });
    });

    var allFound = true;
    searchForWords.forEach(function(word){
        if(!word[1]){
            allFound=false;
            return;
        }
    });

    if(allFound){
        alert('all words found');
    }else{
        alert('did not find all words!');
    }
};

function openWindow(wId) {
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.write('<html><head><title>test</title>');
    w.document.write($("#test" + wId).html());
    w.document.write('</body></html>');
    w.document.close();
    return w;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtxK9/1/

Comment: I looked at both ways and same problem is that you assumed i know number of page (windows) opened. I don't know. if there is a way to get number of open windows and check in everyone, it would be great

Comment: @MoAdel basically the number of windows is irrelevant, you can call open window any way you like and as many times as you want, but you always need to store it (push it) in an array (windows array) as shown in order to iterate it afterwards and search the content of each window. So the test content part as well as calling the openWindow with ids four times is only to create a sample data in the test environment. What you really need is an array or a data structure with the words you are searching and the searchContent function,or simply iterating the windows array to search content.